# Initialise controller state in EmberJs: Route#setupController vs Controller#init

Tags: javascript, ember.js, controller, routes

There appear to be two alternative ways to set the initial state of a controller in EmberJs:

- [Route#setupController](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_setupController)
- [Controller#init](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Controller.html#method_init)

When is it appropriate to use one over the other? Are they equivalent?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generally speaking, `Controller#init` gets called only once when the (usually singleton) controller is created, while `Route#setupController` is called each time the route is entered.

Any model-related properties should be set from `Route#setupController`. Other default setup can be handled in `Controller#init`.

In most Ember apps I have worked on, `Route#setupController` is used more often than `Controller#init`.

Comment: +1 and check @lukemelia. Thanks for the answer - I'll go with `Route#setupController` as the default, and reserve `Controller#init` for special cases.